# How do i implement CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, uicollectionview, pfquerytableviewcontrolle

I am using Parse **PFQueryTableViewController**, it shows images in a list, i want to use **CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout** to show the images in a grid way like instagram, how do i implement this? i did the cocoapod but the demo code is way different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using xib or story board

```
select collectionView -> go to attribute inspector -> layout - select custom -> CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout
```

Include this delegate **CHTCollectionViewDelegateWaterfallLayout** in .h file and the use those delegate methods and then you are ready to go .

Comment: after i include the .h file, what do i do?

Comment: go to the CHTCollectionViewDelegateWaterfallLayout and add the required methods in .m file .

Comment: how do you know which are required?

Comment: do i add the methods on top of the existing uicollectionview protocols?

Comment: - (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

Comment: read the .h file the it is written which method is required and which is optional .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98226/discussion-between-sourav-and-farhan).